# Flutter: Application stucks while is encrypting

Tags: flutter, encryption, crypt

I have a problem encrypting and decrypting my video file and it encrypting video file. there is no any error. but it stucks while is encrypting and decrypting video files. I use asynchronous method. but it still stucks. my code below.

encrypt:

```
Future sifrele() async {
    try {
      crypt.setOverwriteMode(AesCryptOwMode.on);
      encFilepath = await crypt.encryptFile(realPath + '/WhatCarCanYouGetForAGrand.mp4', realPath + '/video.mp4.aes');
      print('The encryption has been completed successfully.');
    } on AesCryptException catch (e) {
      if (e.type == AesCryptExceptionType.destFileExists) {
        print('The encryption has been completed unsuccessfully.');
      }
      return;
    }
  }
```

decrypt:

```
Future decrypting() async {
    var videos = File(realPath + "/ElephantsDream.mp4.aes");
    try {
      realPath = await crypt.decryptFile(realPath + '/video.mp4.aes', realPath + '/cozulen.mp4');
      print('The decryption has been completed successfully.');
    } on AesCryptException catch (e) {
      if (e.type == AesCryptExceptionType.destFileExists) {
        print('The decryption has been completed unsuccessfully.');
      }
      return;
    }
  }
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the other users come here, the answer on the same topic is here [Flutter: run multiple methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64427551/flutter-run-multiple-methods/64437579#64437579)

Comment: it works. thanks. but everyone have to read comment. because I add "static" to head of function.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid jank, you need to perform expensive computations like this in the background. On Android, this means scheduling work on a different thread. In Flutter, you can use a separate [Isolate](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-isolate/Isolate-class.html) and [Compute](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/compute.html). you should probably need something like this:

```
void _Startdecrypting(){
   compute(decrypting, /** If you need any input for your method put them here **/);
}



decrypting() {
    var videos = File(realPath + "/ElephantsDream.mp4.aes");
    try {
      realPath = crypt.decryptFile(realPath + '/video.mp4.aes', realPath + '/cozulen.mp4');
      print('The decryption has been completed successfully.');
    } on AesCryptException catch (e) {
      if (e.type == AesCryptExceptionType.destFileExists) {
        print('The decryption has been completed unsuccessfully.');
      }
      return;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I try Isolate. but I dont know how can I do it. can you give me example ?

Comment: @FesaTR take a look at [this link](https://www.didierboelens.com/2019/01/futures-isolates-event-loop/)

Comment: My english is not perfect. If you have a example, can you write here please ?

Comment: @FesaTR Unfortunately i also do not have much experience with it.