# Flutter: run multiple methods

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-isolates

I have a big problem. If I want to encrypt my video file, my application is freezing until that method finishing. But there is no error. How can I code my application does not freeze. thanks.

```
Future sifrele() async {
  String realPath =
    "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.android.xxxx/files";

    var crypt = AesCrypt('sefa');
    try {
      crypt.setOverwriteMode(AesCryptOwMode.on);
      String encFilepaths = await crypt.encryptFile(
          realPath + '/WhatCarCanYouGetForAGrand.mp4',
          realPath + '/video.mp4.aes');
      print('The encryption has been completed successfully.');
      //print('Encrypted file: $encFilepath');

    } on AesCryptException catch (e) {
      if (e.type == AesCryptExceptionType.destFileExists) {
        print('The encryption has been completed unsuccessfully.');
      }
      return;
    }
  }
```

Comment: you should use isolates for this encrption

Comment: If you have a code example, can you share for me please :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the function type of your function from `Future` to `FutureOr`, add a parameter to the function (even if you don't need it)
and use compute. it will work perfectly.

Before

`Future sifrele() async {`

After

`FutureOr sifrele(String para) async {`

compute

```
  doTheEncryption() {
    compute(sifrele, 'Pass the value of the parameter here if you need it');
  }
```

Another one important thing the definition of the function `sifrele` must be a top level, meaning not inside the class, put it outside the class.
The function *doTheEncryption()* (or whaterver you name it) maybe inside the class no problem.

Comment: thank you very much. it works. but I add "static" to head. it is "static FutureOr sifrele(String para) async {}"

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
Maybe will work if you put code for encryption in isolate.
For that use method compute.

```
void _startEncrypting()
{
compute(sifrele, /** Here put your parameters if you need them **/);
}

sifrele() async {
String realPath = "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.android.xxxx/files";

var crypt = AesCrypt('sefa');
try {
  crypt.setOverwriteMode(AesCryptOwMode.on);
  String encFilepaths = await crypt.encryptFile(
      realPath + '/WhatCarCanYouGetForAGrand.mp4',
      realPath + '/video.mp4.aes');
  print('The encryption has been completed successfully.');
  //print('Encrypted file: $encFilepath');

} on AesCryptException catch (e) {
  if (e.type == AesCryptExceptionType.destFileExists) {
    print('The encryption has been completed unsuccessfully.');
  }
  return;
}
```

}

Comment: it gives this error to me. "E/flutter (14930): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type '(Type) => dynamic'
"